# Search stringlist, remove match and save to file

Tags: delphi-7

Got help yesterday regarding matching the content of a stringlist to a single string, but what if I want to delete the match from the stringlist, then save to file? In the example below I try to count backwards to prevent index out of bounds, but when I delete I still get index out of bounds and I'm not really sure why.. Delete is outside the loop because of the Break in the loop, isn't it? Working example would be great and a explanation why this and that so I could finally learn this..

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
  SL: tStringlist;
  Str: ansistring;
begin
  SL := Tstringlist.Create;
  SL.LoadFromFile('filter.txt');
  Str := Edit1.Text;
  Found := False;

  for i := SL.Count -1 downto 0 do
    if AnsiContainsText(Str, SL[i]) then
      begin
        Found := True;
        Break;
      end;

  if Found then
    ShowMessage('MATCH FOUND: ' +SL[i]);
  SL.Delete(i); // index out of bounds
  SL.SaveToFile('filter.txt');
  SL.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable i used by the for has no reliable value outside of the for loop. Their use should be limited to the inside of the loop. And you execute the SL.Delete(i) always even if no match is found. If you want several statements inside of an if then block, use begin end.

Change it to in order to fix this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
  SL: tStringlist;
  Str: ansistring;
begin
  SL := Tstringlist.Create;
  try
    Found := False;
    SL.LoadFromFile('filter.txt');
    Str := Edit1.Text;
    for i := SL.Count -1 downto 0 do
      if AnsiContainsText(Str, SL[i]) then
      begin
        ShowMessage('MATCH FOUND: ' +SL[i]);
        SL.Delete(i); // index out of bounds
        Found := True;
        Break;
      end;
    if Found then
      SL.SaveToFile('filter.txt');
  finally
    SL.Free; // Assure the SL is freed.
  end;
end;
```

An alternative is to remove found and add an integer parameter that is assigned to -1. If a match is found set it to the current value of i and use that parameter outside of the loop. Or you can use a while loop.